# Python Bokeh xy scatter plot and color mapping using palette

Tags: python, bokeh

I have three list and I want plot a xy scatter plot in bokeh but color of plot points would depend on value of Y but scaled to value specfied in list 'z'. Note here that 'z' is of different size from x and y

How could I do it?

```
`  x = list(range(1, 51)) # Data points
  y = random.sample(range(0, 100), 50) # Temperature observed
  z = list(range(0, 100)) color bar temp range.

  source = ColumnDataSource('.....????..........')
  cmap = linear_cmap(field_name='?', palette="Spectral6", low=?, high=?)

  r = p.scatter(y, y, color=cmap, size=15, source=source)`
```

I tried following the example given on "https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/data/linear_cmap_colorbar.html" but did not have any success.

Comment: Please show the actual code you tried that did not work. SO is for answering specific questions about existing code, not for writing code from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Lots going on here that needs attention to get the most out of Bokeh.

**1. Data Preparation**

Since your 'z' values (representing the scaling factor) have a different range than 'y' (temperature), you need to normalize them. A common approach is min-max normalization:

```py
import numpy as np

def normalize(data, min_val=0, max_val=1):
    return (data - min(data)) / (max(data) - min(data)) * (max_val - min_val) + min_val

z_normalized = normalize(z)
```

**2. Create a ColumnDataSource**

You will need the normalized 'z' values in your data source for the color mapping.

```py
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    temperature=y,  # Use 'y' for the color field
    z=z_normalized
))
```

**3. Linear Color Mapper**

Set the `field_name` to the column in your data source containing the values that will drive the color mapping (in this case, 'temperature'). You might want to scale the `low` and `high` values of the color mapper if there are outliers in your data, ensuring good visual representation.

```py
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper

cmap = LinearColorMapper(field_name='temperature', palette="Spectral6", 
                         low=min(y), high=max(y))
```

**4. Plot and Apply Color Mapping**

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show 

p = figure(title="Temperature Plot with Color Scaling")
p.scatter('x', 'y', size=15, source=source,
          color={'field': 'temperature', 'transform': cmap})
```

Like I said a bit going on there and I won't be able to hand-hold it all the way, but understanding these bigger moves on the structure and intent will help you get the last few.

Comment: x = Combined_Data_Air[X1]
y = Combined_Data_Air[Y1a]
z = Combined_Data_Air['XXXXXXXX']

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict( x = x,y=y,z = z))
cmap = linear_cmap(field_name='z', palette="Turbo256",low = 500, high = 2000)
s1.circle(x= 'x', y ='y', source=source,color=cmap, legend_label=Y1a,size=2)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Combined_Data_Air[X1]
y = Combined_Data_Air[Y1a]
z = Combined_Data_Air['xxxxxxx']

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict( x = x,y=y,z = z))
cmap = linear_cmap(field_name='z', palette="Turbo256",low = 500, high = 2000)
s1.circle(x= 'x', y ='y', source=source,color=cmap, legend_label=Y1a,size=2)
```

X1 and Y1a are Pandas column names. Above is code which worked for me. Thanks for all the help from members.

Comment: FYI: the method `s1.scatter()` is recommended instead of `s1.circle()`.